# How to call a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
I have a method find_all_media in model abc.rb. Model xyz and abc has relationship, 
abc :has_many xyzs and
xyz :belongs_to abc



# abc.rb

method is in abc model
def self.find_all_media(media_name)

  if self.media_name == self.xyz.media_name
     return media_name
  end
end 

### view file
<% @abc.xyzs.each do |xyz| %>
<tr>
<td><%=h xyz.media_name %></td>
<td><%=h xyz.type %></td>
<td>I want to call method find all_media here ?? </td>
</tr>


I tried but not working, any
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your

```
def self.find_all_media(media_name)

  if self.media_name == self.xyz.media_name
     return media_name
  end
end
```

Method is a class method (self). So, you are trying to access you class method from your class instance

```
@abc
```

You have two options

1 - Make the method an instance method (by removing the 'self')

2 - Call your method as `Abc.find_all_media`

And just as a best practice,

Do not call models directly from your views, Do it through the controller, or helper

and if your 'find_all_media' method is someting to do with database query consider

```
:scope (in rails 3.x) (named_scope in rails 2.x)
```

HTH

sameera

Comment: Thanks Sameera. Can you please tell why we use self?? my question can be solved without using self. When we should use class method and instance method.

Comment: hi @user659068, Basic is If your method is doing a common action across all the models use class method (Thats why find is a ActiveRecord class method Ex. User.find) and when u want to do something specific to a give model user instance method (Ex get_amount ) this method will the current objects amount as @use1.get_amount will be 10 and @user2.get_amount will be 20, HTH sameera

Comment: check these out http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/ http://www.rubyfleebie.com/understanding-class-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: on using this in xyz_controller.rb @all_media = Abc.find_all_media(media_name) i am getting error undefined local variable or method `media_name'???

Comment: Hi, either you have to define the variable as 'media_name' or you have to pass the parameter Ex: params[:media_name]

Comment: Hi Sameera, how I can use the output from this in xyz/view file               def self.find_all_media(media_name)

  if self.media_name == self.xyz.media_name
     return media_name
   end

Answer (score 0):

Use `Abc.find_all_media`. If youi use `self` in method name it means this method is going to be used with model itself, not with object. Hope it'll help

Comment: In Xyz controller/ @xyz = Abc.find_all_mediae(media_name) I get error undefined local variable or method 'media_name'??